# Can't figure out how to use angularFireCollection in my service

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I must be missing something very simple.  I've seen a bunch of examples of angularFireCollection but no examples using in the way i'm using it in a service (perhaps that's the issue?).   here's my code which is getting an angular injection error unknown provider:

```
angular.module('CommentBoxService', [])
  .service('CommentBoxSvc', ['$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location','angularFireCollection',
      function ($rootScope, $stateParams, $http, $location, $firebase, angularFireCollection) {
      var commentFireBase = null;
      var user; var type;
      var getFireBaseRef = function () {
          user = ($location.absUrl().split('/'))[4].replace('#', '');

          getType();

          commentFireBase = angularFireCollection('https://XXX/users/' + user + '/comment-boxes/' + type);

          return commentFireBase;
      }


      return {
      getFireBaseRef : getFireBaseRef 
        }
  }]);
```

am i missing something with the injection method?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: angularFireCollection was removed in 0.5 or so; that's almost 6 months old. Please check out the new version and API.